# How to stop pytest test execution for all the scripts when certain condition occurs?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pytest, appium

I am running my python selenium test script in parallel using pytest. I want to stop entire test suit execution if certain condition becomes true in any of the test case? Do we have any functions or methods to do so?

I tried with sys.exit(), pytest.exit(), raising keyboard interrupt exception but all these will only stop current test case and move on to the next test case. I can't use pytest -x or pytest --maxfail=1 since testcase might also fail for some other reasons but not for particular condition which i am expecting to fail.

Comment: Can you showoff your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How come this hasn't been addressed yet?!